# What is Derrida's différance?

Tags: meaning, derrida

I am very perplexed by the concept of différance. Is it even a concept at all? I've had some sources saying otherwise. How should I interpret this?

Comment: See Zeynep Direk & Leonard Lawlor (editor), [A Companion to Derrida](https://books.google.it/books?id=tOT2AwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover), Wiley-Blackwell (2014), **Ch.3 Difference**.

Comment: Could you perhaps say something about what you understand différance to be?

Comment: Could you make this more specific after reading, say, [Wikipedia's Différance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff%C3%A9rance)? The word is a play on "difference", in that "meaning" is constituted merely by differences between signs in a structure, and "deferral", in that meaning is perpetually deferred because every use changes the structure, and therefore all meanings it constitutes. Différance is the central concept of Derrida's philosophy, kind of like determinate negation is for Hegel, but Hegel's intent was to find objective meanings while Derrida's is to deconstruct them altogether.

Comment: Linked to [structuralism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structuralism) and to the linguist [De Saussure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferdinand_de_Saussure) with his theory about languages and systems of signs; [Cours de linguistique générale (1916)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferdinand_de_Saussure#Course_in_General_Linguistics): "In language there are only differences. A linguistic system is a series of differences of sound combined with a series of differences of ideas".